# Multiplication Loop not multiplying

Tags: javascript, loops

Trying to loop the arguments entered and return the arguments as the total multiplication:

```
let lightCode = { //Creates Object.

Multiply: function() { //Multiplys all arguments.

    const total = 0;

    for(const i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {

        console.log(arguments[i]);

        total *= arguments[i];

    }

    return total;

}
}
    lightCode.Multiply(12, 16)
```

Comment: Assign `const total=1` And Try that

Comment: I believe that `for(const i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)`should throw an error, you can not reassign a value of a primitive, which number is. You should use `let`instead. Same for `const total = 0` – it should be `let`.

Comment: any value multiplied by 0 will give you 0.

Comment: And the problem is also, than you are multiplying aruments with total, which is initially `0`. If you multiply *anything* with zero, what the result will be? Try start with `1`.

Comment: @user2932057 Brilliant that worked! Many thanks, I am curious for learning purposes as to why setting total to 1 works?

Comment: As you can see in comments – multiplying anything with zero yields zero.

Comment: @user3710372 - Same Thing I also experienced while writing logics :)

Comment: @HynekS Ah I see, makes sense ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems, one of which is that you can not reassign a value to a constant. Second you're setting total = 0 first. By doing that you'll be multiplying everything by 0.

So in order to solve your problem you need a if conditional to check if total is 0, if is 0 you assign the property total to the argument in the loop, if not you multiply it.

```
let lightCode = { //Creates Object.

    Multiply: function() { //Multiplys all arguments.

       let total = 0;
       for(let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
          if(total === 0) total = parseFloat(arguments[i]);
          else total *= parseFloat(arguments[i]);

       }

      return total;

   }
}
console.log(lightCode.Multiply(12, 16));
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to read about [const, let, var](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-es6-var-let-or-const-ba58b8dcde75) and when to use them. There are (at least) two mistakes in your code:

1. `const total = 0` => since total is declared using the `const` identifier, it means that its value is going to be constant during your program. And what does constant mean? That it stays the same. But the line `total *= arguments[i];` wants to change it, resulting into an error. Also, initializing the total with 0 makes the final results to be 0 (remember that the multiplication identity element is 1).
2. `const i = 0` => same thing; `i++` wants to increment the value of i, but you declared it as const.

Running your code and opening the console you can clearly say an error message: `"Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable."`.

Cheers!

```js
let lightCode = {
    Multiply: function() { 

        var total = 1;

        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            console.log(arguments[i]);
            total *= arguments[i];
        }

        return total;

    }
}

lightCode.Multiply(12, 16)
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in the comments, there is more than one error in the code, first you are assigning the variables as const which is not correct in this case, the rule of thumb is to use let every time you need to reassign a variable (meaning, when you need to use the `=`symbol again), otherwise use const. Also as pointed in the comments you should not initialize the variable with zero, otherwise the loop will always return zero.

Here is a working snippet:

```
const lightCode = { //Creates Object.
    Multiply: function() { //Multiplys all arguments.
        let total = 1; // can not be zero, otherwise the loop will always return zero

        for(let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            console.log(arguments[i]);
            total *= arguments[i];
        }

       return total;

    }
}

lightCode.Multiply(12, 16)
```

Notice how I am using const for the lightCode variable, because this object is never reassigned (meaning, you won't use the `=` to assign a new value again) and instead for total I'm using `let`, because is reassigned on every loop interaction.